# Add multiple products to cart

Tags: php

I have some problem with the logic and any help would be appreciated:

```
$total_add = $_POST['xTotalNumProduct'];

if(ISSET($_SESSION['cart']['CartTotalNum']) && $_SESSION['cart']['CartTotalNum'] > 0) {
    $CartTotalNum = $_SESSION['cart']['CartTotalNum'];
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_add; $i++) {

        for ($x=1; $x<=$CartTotalNum; $x++) {
            if ($cart['ItemId'.$x] == $_POST['xPdt'.$i.'Id']) { // this will only check the first key ie $cart['ItemId1]
                $cart['ItemQty'.$x] = $_POST['xPdt'.$i.'Qty'];
            }
            else {
                $CartTotalNum = $CartTotalNum + 1;
                $cart['ItemId'.$CartTotalNum] = $_POST['xPdt'.$i.'Id'];
                $cart['ItemQty'.$CartTotalNum] = $_POST['xPdt'.$i.'Qty'];
            }
        }
    }
    $cart['CartTotalNum'] = $CartTotalNum;

} else {
    $cart = array();
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_add; $i++) {
        $cart['ItemId'.$i] = $_POST['xPdt'.$i.'Id'];
        $cart['ItemQty'.$i] = $_POST['xPdt'.$i.'Qty'];      
    }
    $cart['CartTotalNum'] = $total_add;
}
```

The problem with the above script is that it only checks the $cart['ItemId1] and if not equal it will add to cart without checking $cart['ItemId2], $cart['ItemId3] etc.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You have your else adding to the cart inside of the for loop. If you don't want $CartTotalNum incremented until after the loop is done, it needs to be outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but for some other reason, I need the $CartTotalNum available in the $_SESSION

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly bad code:

```
            $cart['ItemQty'.$x] = $_POST['xPdt'.$i.'Qty'];
                          ^^^^^
```

Why build dynamic keys? You can use a multi-dimensional arrays quiet easily:

```
   $_SESSION['cart'][$itemID]['quantity'] = $_POST[...];
```

Keying your cart by the itemID allows all of the item's cart data to be kept in one place, instead of scattered everywhere.

And note that similar constructs can be used in your form field names, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="foo[bar][baz][42]" ... >
```

would give you

```
$_REQUEST['foo']['bar']['baz'][42]
```

to work with when the form's submitted.

Comment: Coz I am taking over existing site with some infrastructure already been built earlier. I tried to simply that but starting to realize even more modification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked years ago, but for anyone running into it now, this is what worked for me.

I put this HTML in my page:

```
<form method="post" action="/">

    <input type="hidden" name="E24MT1260" value="23">
    <input type="hidden" name="ACFIT60060015" value="14">

    <input type="hidden" name="programatic_add_to_cart" value="true">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">

</form>
```

And added this to my functions.php

```
<?php

    add_action('wp_loaded', function() {
        global $woocommerce;

        if (!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['programatic_add_to_cart'])){ 
            global $woocommerce;

            foreach ($_POST as $sku => $quantity) {

                $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($sku);
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);
            }

            wp_redirect( '/cart' );
            exit;
        }

    });

?>
```